# foreach stops after DOMDocument length changed

Tags: php, foreach, domdocument

I've got a problem with a forach loop and replaceChild, because when i replace the Child for which the foreach is looping through it stops. How can I prevent this behaviour ?

Here is the Code i have;

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($this->template);
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName("func") as $pnode) {
  echo "CALLED!";
  $attr = $pnode->getAttribute('type');
  $function = $pnode->nodeValue;
  if (array_key_exists($function, parent::$located_functions)) {
    $arr = parent::$located_functions[$function];
    if (class_exists($arr[1])) {
      $call = $arr[1]::$arr[0]();
      $divnode = $dom->createElement("div");
      $this->addHTML($divnode, $call);
      $pnode->parentNode->replaceChild($divnode, $pnode);
      echo "LNG: " . $dom->getElementsByTagName("func")->length;
      $this->template = $dom->saveXML($pnode->parentNode);
    }
  }
}
```

Before I start the script "$dom->getElementsByTagName("func")->length" is 2, "LNG:" gives me 1 after the replaceChild (because I replaced it with HTML Code from $call). Now the loop seems to stop (maybe he thinks that he allready looped through, because the length is now 1 and he is at length 1).
If I don't call replaceChild it will work as expected, but with replaceChild it doesn't work. "Called" is also only displayed once, so the if-clauses shouldn't be the Problem.

But how can I prevent this?

Comment: Have you enabled error logging/displaying? I'm 100% sure that `foreach` loop, meaning the whole script, stops because of an error.

Comment: Error reporting is "E_ALL" and display_errors is on, so this shouldn't be the Problem...